# Create instance of HTMLInputElement

Tags: javascript

I want to extract a user name and password pair and its corresponding form element on a 'Log in' page by analyzing Document Object Model (DOM) objects.

First, all the `HTMLInputElement` objects within the `HTMLDocument` object of the 'Log in' page are to be collected. Next, the password object is located by examining its special attribute `type="password"`.

Comment: The title of your question and the body of it don't quite match up, they seem to be asking different questions. I've answered both.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Answering the *body* of your question:**

You can *find* elements using [`document.getElementsByTagName`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-A6C9094). E.g.:

```
function findThePasswords() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
        input,
        index;
    for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
        input = inputs[index];
        if (input.type === 'password') {
            // Whatever
        }
    }
}
```

Use this knowledge only to benefit Humanity, not in an evil quest for global domination. ;-)

**Answering the *title* of your question:**

You *create* elements via [`document.createElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-2141741547), e.g.:

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = "password";
document.getElementById('someForm').appendChild(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById
document.getElementsByTagName
```

For Examply:

```
document.getElementById('navigation').getElementsByTagName('a')[3];
    returns the fourth link inside the element with the ID 'navigation'
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[2].getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
    returns the first paragraph inside the third div in the document.
```